# cannot convert mkv to mp4

Tags: windows-7, video, conversion, mp4, matroska

I'm using xvid4psp video converter. But I can't convert the mkv file to an mp4. what do I do?

Comment: Use another converter..

Comment: More infos, specify the OS ?

Comment: @kami:I'm using windows 7, I can convert avi's to mp4's but not the mkv's,
@aviator:What other converter can you suggest?

Comment: http://www.virtualdub.org/ should work, but you need to know what you're doing, and have the right plugins (NOT user friendly, extremely powerful).

Comment: @user23950: http://www.effectmatrix.com/total-video-converter/

Comment: @user23950 also try AnyVideo Converter http://filehippo.com/download_any_video_converter/

Comment: What happens when you try? An error? An incomplete or otherwise hosed mp4?

Comment: Please provide more info on the mkv you are trying to convert. What streams does it have (codec of the streams - use mediainfo for that).

Answer (score 3):

ffmpeg will do the trick.

```
ffmpeg -i foo.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy foo.mp4
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to play the MKV files?

Do you have [Haali Media Splitter](http://haali.su/mkv/) installed?

Without it Windows does not know how to deal with MKV files and therefore xvid4psp will not either.

Answer (score 2):

[MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/) converts from about anything to about anything. Codecs are all contained within so you don't need to install anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success converting various video formats including MKV to MP4 (M4V) using [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/details.php).

Answer (score 0):

Like JustinStolle said, HandBrake is a good choice (though I've found that many people have a hard time using it). You might have better luck playing / [converting with VLC player](http://tom.zickel.org/vlcmp4/), or using a dedicated converter like [Hamstersoft](http://video-converter.hamstersoft.com/en/).

Answer (score 0):

Like others suggested, using another converter is one of the ways to solve the problem.

I would like to add (I havn't used the below converters ever but if you want to try it anyway below is the link)

1) [mkv To mp4 converter](http://www.mkvtomp4converter.com/)

2) [Online Video converter](http://us.onlinevideoconverter.com/)

I use and recommend "ImTOO Video Converter" but its not free

Answer (score 0):

[Freemake video converter](http://www.freemake.com/offline/offline_all/) will do your job easily and its support many formats and very easy to use.